# DataFrame accessing nested keys in list within dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

The following data is part of a much larger `dataframe` with a lot of nested keys.
Say I want to access "humidity" or "windSpeed" How would I do that?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data":[{"time":1422802800,"humidity":0.62,"windSpeed":2.62}]})
```

The purpose is to select only certain keys and append them to a CSV file, rather then appending the entire `dataframe` to the CSV file.

Comment: Are you wanting to only write some columns or just 1 column? You could add the desired columns using my answer and then write just the cols of interest to csv

Comment: @EdChum, I altered the code above.

Comment: You should use `read_json` to read this in, also you've modified your question quite substantially, I'd post another question as it's not good practice to increment your requirements especially after you accepted my answer. Basically after loading this json you should be able to use my code to add the data as a new column and then you just select the cols of interest and write just those out, i.e. `df['hourly'].to_csv()` You can get the hourly data using the answer I posted

Comment: @EdChum thank you for all the feedback. I edited back the original posting to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to use `apply` with a `lambda` and index into the dict:

```
In[69]:
df['data'].apply(lambda x: x['time'])

Out[69]: 
0    1422802800
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

and like-wise for humidity:

```
In[71]:
df['data'].apply(lambda x: x['humidity'])

Out[71]: 
0    0.62
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

I'd advise against storing non-scalar values in a df, it's non-performant as you lose any vectorised advantages of using dataframes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still a bit lost how to alter my code. I've added the line of code above. Could you guide me in the right direction?